# Creating a Tree recursively

Tags: c, tree

I'm trying to create a Tree recursively in C.

So far I have done the code below. But when compiling I get the following error massages;

> error: request for member ‘esq’ in something not a structure or union
>        MakeTree(H-1, p->left, p);
>                         ^
>    error: request for member ‘dir’ in something not a structure or union
>        MakeTree(H-1, p->right, p);
>                         ^

What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct nohh {
  int info;
  struct nohh *left;
  struct nohh *right;
  struct nohh *up;
} nohh, *noh;

void MakeTree(int H, noh *p, noh *u);

int main(){
  noh p = NULL;
  int h;

  printf("What is the Tree height? ");
  scanf("%d\n", &h);

  MakeTree(h, &p, &p);

  return 0;
}

void MakeTree(int H, noh *p, noh *u){

  while(H>=0){
    p = malloc(sizeof(noh));
    (*p)->up = *u;
    MakeTree(H-1, p->left, p);
    MakeTree(H-1, p->right, p);
  }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: `noh` is pointer to `struct nohh`.

Comment: please finish the translation, then compile it again and post the error and the code.

Comment: Sorry,I hadnt translate all the code to english.
I belive now its ok.

Comment: `p->left` should be `&(*p)->left`. also your use of `malloc` is wrong.

Comment: Why is malloc wrong?

Comment: @mch why there is problem with p? its a pointer so it seems normal to me to use -> without &(*p)

Comment: because noh is a pointer, you want to malloc space for the struct, so `*p = malloc(sizeof(nohh));` should be correct.

Comment: @Anton.P `p` in MakeTree is a pointer to pointer to struct, so you have to dereference twice and then you want the address of the member => `&(*p)->left`

Comment: @mch that solved my compilation warnings. 
Nut the loop seens to not reach an end.
Can you see why?

Comment: @kaiser yes, remove it, you don't need it. see my answer.

Comment: @mch hi, i am having difficulty understanding the typedef, when i use `typedef struct nohh {
  ... *noh;` is it the same as: `typedef struct nohh* noh` i.e noh will be a pointer to the strcut?

Comment: @Anton.P yes, `noh` is of type `struct nohh*`.

Comment: @Dettorer thanks i didnt know you can define two types in one typedef and didnt know ytou can define a pointer to the type

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void MakeTree(int H, noh *p, noh *u)
{
  if (H>0)
  {
    *p = malloc(sizeof(nohh));
    (*p)->up = *u;
    MakeTree(H-1, &(*p)->left, p);
    MakeTree(H-1, &(*p)->right, p);
  }
}
```

this should fix your problems:

you want to do it recursive, so you don't need the while loop.
you want to malloc the size of the struct and not of the pointer and write it to the place of the original `p` in main.
`p` in MakeTree is a pointer to pointer to struct, so you have to dereference twice and then you want the address of the member => `&(*p)->left` and `&(*p)->right`.

a suggestion: don't call a struct nohh and the pointer to it noh, that's not readable.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is somewhat more readable avoiding pointers to pointers.

```
struct nohh {
  int info;
  struct nohh *left;
  struct nohh *right;
  struct nohh *up;
} ;

struct nohh *MakeTree(int h, struct nohh *up)
{
  if (h >= 0)
  {
    struct nohh *p = (struct nohh *)malloc(sizeof(struct nohh));
    p->up = up;
    p->left  = MakeTree(h - 1, p);
    p->right = MakeTree(h - 1, p);
    return p ;
  }

  return NULL ;
}


int main(){
  struct nohh *p ;
  int h;

  printf("What is the Tree height? ");
  scanf("%d", &h);

  p = MakeTree(h, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```